# DecisionTree Classifier in scikit learn features return the value -2, what does it mean

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, decision-tree

The tree._feature for DecisionTreeClassifier and DecisionTreeRegressor returns the value -2 a few times in the end. Is this because they are leaf nodes? Can I assume any -2 value as leaf node features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes. The object variable `.tree_.feature` returns `-2` when there is no split on that node, which occurs if and only if the node is a leaf (when the tree was grown without pruning, ie.  `fit(..., ccp_alpha=0)`).

While it's not 100% clear in the `help()` documentation, a reference to this can be found inside the code here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx

where the `feature` value is set to the static variable `TREE_UNDEFINED = -2`.

Comment: A more "official" way is on this example on the sciki-learn website:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py

To find the child node is to check if `tree_. children_left == tree_.children_right`. If it does, then the node does not have two different children, and thus cannot be split, and thus must be a leaf node.